# Can top plate of partition wall be removed where it joins load bearing wall?

Tags: bathroom, walls, load-bearing

Is it okay to remove a partition wall that has its top plate going under the I beam of a load bearing wall?

Would I just cut the top plate flush with the studs of the load bearing wall?

The red arrows indicate what I want to remove. The yellow lines are where the joists are located.

https://imgur.com/a/d9tIoAV
https://imgur.com/a/6i9aA9d

I want to remove the doorway part from the partition wall between a shower and main part of a bathroom. I only want to have part of the partition wall remaining so the ceiling is continuous from the main bathroom into the shower and the wall is continuous between the shower and bathroom. I've already removed the door header and jack studs.

The steel I beam ends right after it intersects with the top plate of the partition wall. There is a duct going parallel with the joists almost directly over the partition wall after the beam ends. One of the pictures shows this.

Comment: What is the purpose of the steel beam? By your pre-edit question, it sounded like the beam stops short of that door opening in the bearing wall. If it's not a header for that opening, is it relevant to something on the other side of the back wall? Without an understanding of what exactly is going on, it seems reckless to offer an opinion.

Comment: @popham - The other side of the wall is a family room. The bathroom and family room are on the bottom level of a tri-level on a concrete slab.

Comment: It sounds like a carrier beam hidden in the ceiling in place of a lengthy missing chunk of bearing wall. The concrete slab seems strange for you to have mentioned. That's a soil supported slab that you stand on looking up at the beam? There's not a slab on top of the steel, right?

Comment: Yes the slab is on the floor not above the room.

Comment: If it isn't obvious that the partition wall can safely be removed I'm willing to pay a structural engineer to look at it if that's recommended. I was hoping it would be obvious to someone online with a trained eye.

Comment: Your plan sounds fine. The steel just makes me uneasy in residential construction. Looking at something like this in person, I would poke around a bit to verify that its connection into the bearing wall's top plate was consistent with the shallow carrier beam theory. Hearing about a room on the other side and not a wall is pretty reassuring, at least. If I found that the steel had not been attached to the top plate with substantial anchors, I would want to fix that as part of this scope of work. In person, a trained eye might stick on something that your eye scans across without interest.